# MySQL: make record last in alpha sort

Tags: mysql, sorting, array-reverse

I can make a selected record appear at the beginning of a sorted query:

```
$sql = "SELECT meetID, meetingTitle
FROM meetings
ORDER BY meetingTitle = 'Other Meetings' DESC, meetingTitle DESC";
```

That forces "Other Meetings" to be at the top of an alphabetical array output. I want it to be at the bottom. I can then use array_reverse to place it at the end of the output array, but I am looking for a direct approach with the MySQL query. Is that possible?

Comment: See FIELD() ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ASC` to `DESC`:

```
$sql = "SELECT meetID, meetingTitle
        FROM meetings
        ORDER BY meetingTitle = 'Other Meetings' ASC, meetingTitle DESC";
```

The value of `meetingTitle = 'Other Meetings'` is `1` for `Other Meetings` and `0` for other values. So if you want other values first, you want `0` to be ahead of `1`, and that's ASCending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT meetID, meetingTitle FROM  meetings
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN meetingTitle = 'Other Meetings' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, meetingTitle DESC
```